# Bad Request upload image in iPad/iOS to web2py server

Tags: javascript, ios, xmlhttprequest, web2py, bad-request

I am developing a web browser application where the user must upload a image file to a web2py server.

I am using the traditional way for file input, which, in the iPad, gives the option to either upload an existing picture or take a new one from the camera.

```
<input id='file-input' type='file' accept='image/*' name='fileUpload' onchange='fileSelected(); />
```

And the corresponding javascript for upload:

```
var url = "http://please-help-me.com";          
var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];

var fd2 = new FormData();
fd2.append("upload", file);
fd2.append("id", 123);  

var reader = new XMLHttpRequest();
reader.open('post',url, true); 
reader.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log("Status:" + reader.status);
}
reader.send(fd2);
```

This works fine for the in the desktop browsers, Android browser, but not in the iPad, where it occasionally gives a `400 Bad Request Error`. It doesn't return the error every time. Just sporadically.

Web2py returns this error message:

```
  ERROR:Rocket.Errors.Thread-20:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mdipierro/make_web2py/web2py/gluon/rocket.py", line 1337, in run
  File "/home/mdipierro/make_web2py/web2py/gluon/rocket.py", line 1838, in run_a
pp
  File "/home/mdipierro/make_web2py/web2py/gluon/main.py", line 651, in app_with
_logging
  File "/home/mdipierro/make_web2py/web2py/gluon/main.py", line 532, in wsgibase
  File "/home/mdipierro/make_web2py/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 252, in body
HTTP: 400 BAD REQUEST
```

Searching in the code, it appears the content of the post message is not valid and the web2py `body` function has trouble reading it. The error rises when I try to read the `request.post_vars` data

I've tested the code without sending the image, and only sending other data, and it seems to be working every time. Is there a specific parameter I should add int the request?
Why does it work sometimes, but not all the time?

Thanks